# Is there a way to display how many books are missing every week?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database of a library management system. I have to display how many books are borrowed, returned and missing every week (the weeks that there is any information). If the book is not returned within 7 days it is considered late. If the book has not returned the expected week it is considered missing for that week. The result should look something like this

```
Week | Borrowed | Returned | Missing
-----+----------+----------+---------
4    | 10       | 8        | 2
5    | 5        | 4        | 3
```

I have figured out the borrowed and returned part with this

```
select date_part('week', dateofborrowing) as week,
date_part('year', dateofborrowing) as year, 
count(dateofborrowing) as borrowed, 
null as returned,
null as missing
from borrowing 
group by year,week 
union 
select date_part('week', returndate) as week,
date_part('year', returndate) as year, 
null as borrowed,
count(returndate) as returned,
null as missing
from borrowing 
group by year, week
order by year, week;
```

return looks like this

```
 week | year | borrowed | returned | missing
------+------+----------+----------+---------
   45 | 2018 |        1 |          |
   46 | 2018 |          |        1 |
   51 | 2018 |        1 |          |
   52 | 2018 |          |        1 |
    5 | 2019 |        3 |          |
    6 | 2019 |        4 |          |
    7 | 2019 |        5 |          |
    7 | 2019 |          |        9 |
    8 | 2019 |          |        3 |
   14 | 2019 |        1 |          |
   17 | 2019 |          |        1 |
   36 | 2019 |        1 |          |
   37 | 2019 |        7 |          |
   38 | 2019 |        2 |          |
      |      |          |        0 |
```

Preferably the week 7 should be on the same row if there is a quick fix

However what I'm struggling with is the missing column.
Grateful for any help!

This is the creation of the table borrowing

```
CREATE TABLE Borrowing (
BorrowingID int PRIMARY KEY,
ResourceID int REFERENCES Books(ResourceID),
UserID int REFERENCES Usser(UserID),
DateOfBorrowing date,
ReturnDate date,
Delay int );    // total amount of days a book is delayed
```

some data

```
INSERT INTO borrowing (borrowingid, resourceid, userid, dateofborrowing, returndate, delay)
VALUES (1, 117, 28, '2018-11-11', '2018-11-15', 0),
(2, 118, 30, '2018-12-22', '2018-12-29', 0),
(3, 119, 37, '2019-02-02', '2019-02-12', 3),
(4, 120, 37, '2019-02-02', '2019-02-14', 5),
(5, 121, 11, '2019-04-03', '2019-04-25', 15),
(6, 122, 32, '2019-02-03', '2019-02-11', 1),
(7, 123, 34, '2019-02-05', '2019-02-19', 7),
(8, 124, 39, '2019-02-08', '2019-02-14', 0),
(9, 125, 39, '2019-02-09', '2019-02-14', 0),
(10, 126, 39, '2019-02-10', '2019-02-14', 0),
(11, 127, 15, '2019-02-12', '2019-02-15', 0),
(12, 128, 16, '2019-02-12', '2019-02-16', 0),
(13, 129, 17, '2019-02-13', '2019-02-16', 0),
(14, 130, 18, '2019-02-14', '2019-02-20', 0),
(15, 131, 32, '2019-02-15', '2019-02-20', 0);
```

Comment: Post the structure of the `borrowing` table so we know what the query is operating on, and ideally some sample data (db-fiddle or similar),

Comment: @404 hope that helps

Comment: How do you define whether a book is "missing"?

Comment: @404 oh yeah forgot about that, if the book is not returned within 7 days it is late. So if the book has not returned during the expected week it is missing

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `sum(CASE WHEN Delay >= 7 THEN 1 END) as missing` or something similar.

See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) for more details.